# Is this a correct use of sleep()?

Tags: c, sleep

I'm using sleep like this to grab a frame every 1/25th of a second. OS is Debian 6 armel.

```
#define VIDEO_FRAME_RATE 25.0f

while (RECORDING) {

  sprintf(buffer, "Someting from a data struct that is updated\n"); 
  fprintf(Output, buffer); 
  usecTosleep = (1.0f/VIDEO_FRAME_RATE) * 1000000;
  usleep(usecToSleep);

}
```

Question: What is the guarantee that the loop will output the buffer to Output file descriptor at every 1/25th of a second?
Is there a better way to do this in C? I need it to be as precise as possible to prevent drifting.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly, but can't you just do sleep(.04)?

Comment: You should also be aware your code won't be really going through the loop **exactly** every .04 second. Things like `sprintf`, `printf`, and whatever else you do on your data can take time.

Comment: Windows/Linux/whatever desktop os you are using is not a RTOS. So there are no guarantees of any timing what-so-ever.

Comment: @abuv if he use usecTosleep he can always get the correct framerate by just changing the const

Comment: You'll very likely run into trouble with this (skipped frames etc). You'll probably want a driver which reacts to some hardware event (hysnc or vsync or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "recording operation" still takes some time...

So you need to calculate time that should be spent on on frame (`usecTosleep = (1.0f/VIDEO_FRAME_RATE) * 1000000;`) and then calculate time operation really took, adjust sleep time accordingly:

```
usecTosleep = (1.0f/VIDEO_FRAME_RATE) * 1000000;
lastFrameUsec = 0;

while (RECORDING) {
  sprintf(buffer, "Someting from a data struct that is updated\n"); 
  fprintf(Output, buffer); 
  usecTosleep = (1.0f/VIDEO_FRAME_RATE) * 1000000;

  // currentFrameUec - lastFrameUsec = actual time spending on operation
  currentFrameUsec = getUsecElapsedFromStart();
  actualSleep = usecToSleep - (currentFrameUsec - lastFrameUsec);

  // If there's time to sleep left, sleep
  if(actualSleep > 0){
      usleep(actualSleep);
      lastFrameUsec = getUsecElepasedFromStart();
  } else {
      lastFrameUsec = currentFrameUsec;
  }
}
```

I'm not aware of multi platform `getUsecElapsedFromStart()` so you probably will have to implement your own for example like [this one](http://][1]).

```
int getUsecElapsedFromStart(const struct timespec *tstart)
{
    struct timespec *tnow;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tnow);

     return (int)((tnow tv_sec*10.0e9 + tnow.tv_nsec) - 
            (tstart.tv_ses*10.0e9 + tstart.tv_nsec));
}

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tstart);
while(RECORDING){
    // ...
    currentFrameUsec = getUsecElapsedFromStart(&tstart);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. I don't think the code actually works because currentFrameUsec and lastFrameUsec would quickly go out of range. One way to to clock_gettime twice and get the difference I guess. I think measuring it in this way would definitely get me better results.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your first question, there is no such guarantee. `usleep()` promises only that it will sleep **at least** as long as you tell it to. But it may sleep longer:

```
     The usleep() function suspends execution of the calling process for (at least) usec microseconds.  The
     sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by
     the granularity of system timers.
```